# How to sum the values up based on Team and Month?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Was trying to sum the values up for the revenue in different time period and months.

Have try tried index and sumifs but does not give the results that i am looking for. Not sure if you can help?

[Here is the file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DptJED0oKc1qtlQoPRT7VFCWURxzqLOo)

Comment: Y don't use SUMIFs or SUMPRODUCT,, even,, since if I'm not wrong you want to SUM As for particular date/between 2 Dates !!

Comment: For better understanding please [EDIT] your post  & share the formula you have used for,, help to fix it !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I converted the table on your `Revenue Details` worksheet into a Table and used structured references to aid in understanding.  You can convert back to a range if you prefer.
- I assumed you wanted the results on your worksheet `Revenue Summary`
- I changed the date in `'Revenue Summary'!L2` from `10/28/2019` to `10/1/2019` (so all dates in row 2 are at the first of the month).

To do that you may enter, in `'Revenue Summary'!C3`:

```
=SUMIFS(Rev[[Revenue]:[Revenue]],Rev[[Date Added]:[Date Added]],">="&'Revenue Summary'!C$2,Rev[[Date Added]:[Date Added]],"<=" &EOMONTH('Revenue Summary'!C$2,0),Rev[[Team]:[Team]],$A3)
```

The fill across and down with the formula.

Is this the result you want?

[image]

A similar result can be obtained using Power Query (available in Excel 2010 and later) but it will not have columns for any months that don't have data.

Answer (score 0):

I added one column to your `Revenue Detail` sheet for month using formula `=DATE(YEAR(A3),MONTH(A3),1)`

[image: Revenue Detail Sheet]

Then I simply used pivot table functionality to achieve desired result
[image: Pivot Table]

Please note that I am using excel 2016 and for me I can directly use pivot table without even using creating the additional row. I was not sure if previous versions of excel supports it, so I have added that additional step

Answer (score 0):

*The `SUMPRODUCT` formula along with criteria gets the Revenue total falls in particular month.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- To get unique Team list an array (CSE) formula in cell `K37`.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(L$23:L$34,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($K$36:K36,L$23:L$34),"0")),"")}
  ```
- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.
- Enter this formula in cell `L37` & fill across.

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT( --(MONTH($K$23:$K$34)=L$36)*($L$23:$L$34=$K37)*($M$23:$M$34))
  ```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*